# How to find census tract from latitude and longitude in python

Tags: python, census

I have two data set that I want to merge to find the census tract based on longitude and latitude

The first data set that I am using is the New York City Airbnb Open Data and its latitude and longitude column look like this.

```
latitude    longitude   
40.64749    -73.97237
40.75362    -73.98377
40.80902    -73.94190
40.68514    -73.95976
40.79851    -73.94399
```

The second data set that I am using contains the census block code for coordinates in NY.

```
Latitude    Longitude   BlockCode   
40.48   -74.280000  340230076002012 
40.48   -74.276834  340230076005000 
40.48   -74.273668  340230076003018 
40.48   -74.270503  340230076003004 
40.48   -74.267337  340230074021000
```

I first attempted to calculate the single_pt_haversine (assume the distance's point to have coordinate (0,0)) for the latitude and longitude. Then, I inner join the two data set on the single_pt_haversine, there is not a match between the data sets. I then round up the single_pt_haversine to 3 decimal places and there were some matches in the columns, but only 300 or so rows got returned (out of the 48895 in the first dataset).

Is there a better to do this? Or maybe a package to determine the census tract from coordinate in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Python package `censusgeocode` should be sufficient for your case. So you can try:

```
import censusgeocode as cg 
result = cg.coordinates(x=lng, y=lat)
```

More documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/censusgeocode/

Comment: Converting an answer to a comment :-  I think it should be cg.coordinates not cg.coordinate